# SQL Foreign Key with multiple values in the same column

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, teradata

I am learning SQL and am trying to find solution logic for the below problem:

Table A has 2 columns - HL_ACCT, CUST

Table B has 2 columns - CUST, SAV_ACCT.

CUST is the foreign key.

Imagine the below scenario:
HL_ACCT-1 has 2 CUST -> CUST_1 and CUST_2

I need to fetch the SAV_ACCTs from the table B that has **both** the CUST_1 and CUST_2 associated with it, i.e, foreign key with multiple values.

Edit: Consider Table A to be Account_Customer table with Home Loan Account & customer details and has One-to-Many relationship.
(A HL can be in the name of both "Master Holder" and "Co-holder")

Table B is Customer and Savings account details with Many-to Many relationship. "Master Holder" can hold multiple saving accounts. "Co-holder" can also hold multiple savings accounts. "Master Holder" & "Co-Holder" can hold multiple Joint accounts.

In my scenario, I need all the Joint accounts to be fetched for a Home Loan account.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? It might help if you use more meaningful names for the tables in your question and possibly some example data

Comment: Also, I don't really understand how the columns are supposed to reference each other. With what you are describing it seems to be the exact same table twice, just with their columns flipped

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all the answers/comments. I have edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and `having`.  If I'm following the data model correctly:

```
select b.link_acct
from a join
     b
     on a.cust = b.cust
where a.cust in ('cust_1', 'cust_2')
group by b.link_acct
having count(distinct a.cust) = 2;
```